# Regarding Core Data Model Relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I am trying to understand the concept of relationship in `CoreData` Modeling and its getting little hard to understand as of what entity could be a good sense of having a relationship. Is there a way to have a unique number generated for a relationship that can correspond to another entity as well? So lets say I have a new entity entry, it will have a unique number 101 for relationship info, and details will also have 101 created, and hence can have a corresponding relationship intact somehow. Not sure if `CoreData` Model have this sorted out to have some sort of generator to generate a unique value for both the entities.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you fully understand how Core Data works. Core Data operates on an SQL database, and handles low level things such as unique IDs and keys for you, so you don't have to worry about them.

An entity can have attributes, which are basically primitive values. A relationship is sort of like a two way pointer from one entity to another. If you need to have a reference to an entity from another entity, you use a relationship. If you need to store a boolean value, you use an attribute.

Please clarify your question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @PartiallyFinite, I am trying to create a relationship between two entities, however I want it a unique number/string. So lets say its a Person and Address, can I have a unique id for both of them which can be utilized as a relationship? So if I want to query for the Person, based on the unique id I can fetch the person's Address as well. Thanks.

Comment: You are thinking on too low a level. Core Data does not give you access to unique identifiers of objects. Instead, you use the Editor menu in Xcode to create an `NSManagedObject` subclass for each of your entities, and use an `NSFetchedRequest` to fetch all entities matching conditions you set. When you fetch a person in this way, you can simply use `person.address` to get the address assigned to that person.

Comment: I suggest you follow this tutorial to get started: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @PartiallyFinite, I did went through that tutorial, however I am not sure, how details and info make inverse relationship a true relationship? Just confused at that part. I hope you understand my concern here? I am trying to utilize the main stream primary/foreign key concept here.. Not sure if the relationship does exactly the same behind the picture? Thanks.

Comment: The inverse relationship in that case means that for an entity `FailedBankInfo`, `object.details` is a reference to a `FailedBankDetails` entity, and for that `FailedBankDetails` entity, `object.info` is a reference to a `FailedBankInfo`.

Comment: So, if you have a `FailedBankDetails` object, `object.details.info` would be equal to `object`, so the expression `[object.details.info isEqual:object]` would return `YES`.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite, okay I had to go into its class creation, so now it makes sense as info is itself an Object of FailedBankInfo. However, I think you got a type there, you mean object.info will be same as FailedBankInfo I guess.

Comment: What I'm saying is, in a one-to-one relationship, the `details` property of a `FailedBankInfo` object will point to a `FailedBankDetails` object, and the `info` property of that object will point back to the original `FailedBankInfo` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is a high level library which purpose is to manage and persist an object graph as transparently as possible. How Core Data links objects in the database (which is not necessarily a database by the way) is an implementation detail.

In the model editor, you simply create the entities you need and link them with relationships. Core Data manage the connections for you.

```
Person:
- first_name: string
- middle_name: string
- last_name: string
- private_address: -> Address (to-one relationship)
- work_address: -> Address (to-one relationship)

Address:
- persons: ->> Person (to-many relationship, you may want to reuse an address)
- address1: string
- address2: string
- zip: string
- city: string
- country: string    
...
```

person.first_name returns you the first name of the person, and person.private_address.city returns the person's city of residence as easily. address.persons returns all the persons sharing the same address (private or/and work), as an NSSet. address.persons.count returns how many persons share that address. What you see is an object graph.

Core Data provides you some sort of unique ID for every entity, once the entity is saved at least, objectID, an opaque NSManagedObjectID. You'll maybe better served with the URIRepresentation (again, once the entity is saved). If your intention is to create cross-store relationships, you can use the URIRepresentation or use your own unique ID. It's fairly easy to maintain a per-entity unique ID, or even a per-store unique ID.

But most of the time, you do not have to deal with such low level concerns though. Core Data is pretty good at managing the relationships for you.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to read the [Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) to get a better understanding.

If you come from a SQL background, a relationship basically represents a `FOREIGN KEY` or join table, mapping objects from one another.

So let's say you have a `Company` which has many `Employee`s. You create entities for the two types, and set up a one-to-many relationship between the company and employee (or even many-to-many if an employee works for multiple companies).

Using Core Data you can then easily add, remove, or otherwise access the employees for a given company.

So a relationship is used to associated instances of entities with one another.